# Isn't a differential curve with corners contradictory?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves

While reading "Riemannian Geometry" by M. Do Carmo, I've ran into a confusing remark following the definition of a curve.
The author presents the following definition (2.8, chapter 1) for a curve:

> A differential mapping $c:I \rightarrow  M$ of an interval $I \subset  \mathbb{R}$ into a differentiable manifold M is called a (parametrized) *curve*

Following the definition, Do Carmo remarks:

> Observe that a parametrized curve can admit self-intersections as well as corners.

My Question is - Isn't the geometric interpretation of a "differentiable" is "smooth"? How come a differentiable curve admits a corner?

I'd be glad to see an example for a differentiable curve with a corner.

Many Thanks!

Comment: The map $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$ is a smooth curve with a corner at the origin. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity))

Comment: Thanks a lot, clarified it in a moment.

Comment: What is important to notice is that the derivative of any smooth parametrization of this curve has to vanish there, since it has to do an instant U-turn

Comment: Your conjecture that there can't be corners would be correct if you parameterized the curve by its arc length, for example, or any other parameterization in which the *speed* never goes to zero.

Comment: "The derivative of any smooth parametrization of this curve has to vanish" (at a cusp point) is the main thing here. A "curve" is not a one-dimensional submanifold; it is a function with a given parametrization. It's perfectly possible that a *smooth* curve travels to a single point, slows down, comes to a stop, and then starts again in a different direction. (The tangent vector is well-defined at all points – including the cusp point, where it is zero.) And as the answer below shows, it is possible for such a curve to be $C^\infty$ (but not analytic!)

Comment: We could summarize all this by the following analogy. An object's movement is continuous and differentiable on $t$. An object can follow a non-differentiable path. But at a point where the path is non-differentiable, e.g. a 90° turn, the speed must be $0$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I already gave an example in the comment section showing that a curve can be smooth although it have a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) at some point: the curve $t\in \Bbb R \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$ is such a curve.

However, one could argue that the cusp in the latter example isn't a corner, since there is no angle between the two parts of the curve meeting there.
Indeed, one can still define a tangent to the curve at the cusp geometrically, or by using sufficiently high order derivatives.
Hence, I would like to give an example with a proper angle, where no notion of tangent can exist.

You surely already know that the following function
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
f\colon & \Bbb R &\longrightarrow &\Bbb R \\
& x &\longmapsto &\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} & \text{ if } x \neq 0, \\
0 & \text{ if } x = 0,
\end{cases} 
\end{array}
$$
is smooth, with $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k\geqslant 0$.
If not, take a look at [this](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/positive-smooth-function-with-all-derivatives-vanishing-at-zero/).

Consider the parametrized curve
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
\gamma\colon & \Bbb R &\longrightarrow& \Bbb R^2 \\
& t & \longmapsto & \begin{cases}
(f(t),f(t)) & \text{ if } t>0, \\
(0,0) & \text{ if } t=0,\\
(-f(t),f(t)) &\text{ if } t<0.
\end{cases}
\end{array}
$$
It can be easily shown that $\gamma$ is a smooth curve, even at the origin. Its support is the same as that of the curve $s\in (-1,1) \mapsto (s,|s|)$, and thus has a $90°$ corner at the origin.
Still, it is a smooth curve.

What is important here is that no smooth parametrization of this curve can have a non-zero derivative at the origin.
In other word, this curve has no regular parametrization.
It is the main reason why textbooks usually state their results beginning with "Let $\gamma$ be a regular curve".

Comment: Thanks @Didier, the construction of the 90-degree-cornered-curve was very educating for me.

Comment: One can consider the function $f(x)=0$ if $x\leqslant0$, $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ if $x>0$; then construct $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\gamma(x) = (f(x), f(-x))$. This is a curve that enters the origin from the positive $y$ axis, halts at $(0,0)$, then exits via the positive $x$ axis. See p.45 of Bishop & Goldberg, *Tensor Analysis on Manifolds*, Dover Publications, New York (1980)

Comment: @printf Yes, this also works

Answer (score 2):

Pick a smooth increasing function $\phi : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ such that $\phi = 0$ on $[0, 1/4]$ and $\phi = 1$ on $[3/4, 1]$. Take any two smooth curves $\gamma_1$ from $p$ to $q$ and $\gamma_2$ from $q$ to $r$, both defined on $[0, 1]$. Then the concatenation $\gamma$ of $\gamma_1 \circ \phi$ and $\gamma_2 \circ \phi$ is a smooth curve. Yet visually, while the curve is stuck at $q$, it can turn around and make a corner. After all, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ can be arbitrary smooth curves.